# How do you register a new user in flutter and firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I created an instance of the Firebase auth and then used it to call the method.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email : email, password : password);
```

This throws an exception-

> PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `createuserwithEmailAndPassword` takes named parameters `paramName: value`. You can find the source code here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L57

```
  Future<AuthResult> createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
  })
```

Therefore to register a user, you need to do the following:

```
final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: 'an email',
      password: 'a password',
    ))
        .user;
```

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

After adding the above, execute the command `flutter clean`

Comment: I have done that too.I have passed in the respective values after fetching it form a textfield.

Comment: Sorry I have made the necessary changes in the question.  Again I understand what you mean and have done the same. Initially I thought it was due to no internet acess so I added the permission  in the manifest file. The same exception is thrown.

Comment: Please add await just copy the answer and paste it in ur code

Comment: And make sure u add the firebase plugin in the pubspec file

Comment: I also added await and async.

Comment: Added both core and auth plugins to the .yaml file